# select() for multiple file I/O in C#?

Tags: c#, file-io

Is there functionality in C# standard libraries analogous to [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)?

In particular, the C# program needs to block waiting on I/O events of multiple file streams (not sockets).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're waiting for someone else to write to the file, you can use `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` and look for change events. Otherwise, you can always use `FileStream.BeginRead` and `FileStream.BeginWrite` for asynchronous I/O. Neither of those is very similar to `select()` in terms of interface, but they can achieve the desired result of fast, asynchronous IO.